# Dropzone.JS CreateImage Thumbnails

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, upload

So I noticed that DropzoneJS has the following Configuration Option being: createImageThumbnails (http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-createImageThumbnails).

But I didn't find any proper information to how this configuration option can be used, and how I can save thumbnails on my server by using this option.

I'm currently using Laravel 5.3 to do the whole uploading via DropzoneJS so I would like to have some thumbnail control, so my question here is. Would it be a good way to do it via DropzoneJS and if so how? OR do it php wise?

Thanks for further information in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend using the `createThumbnailFromUrl()` method which implements `createImageThumbnails()`.

The reason being is that - each time you do this, you'll force the user to create the thumbnail on the client side (CPU/Mem resource intensive). Then, they'll have to send the image to the server (Network/Bandwidth intensive).

Instead, I would recommend just creating the thumbnails on the server. You can scale down the images on the client side (the original) for viewing with minimal resource cost (zero network/bandwidth cost).

The server can then handle the thumbnail creation. You can use something such as the [Intervention library's fit() command](http://image.intervention.io/api/fit) for this. Here's an example using a callback to ensure that the image does not get made any larger than the original in either dimension calling `->upsize()`.

```
$img = Image::make('/path/to/my/img.ext');
$img->fit(120, 72, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->upsize();
});
```

Hope this was informative and helpful.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the quick reply and clear information regarding the whole use of the createImageThumbnails option.

I'll give that library you've posted a good read through and try it out!

Much appreciated ;)

Comment: Followup comment to thank you again for the assistance as this was indeed what I needed! And it seems to work perfectly now EXCEPT with SVG files which I'm not having trouble with getting them to upload properly when the thumbnail generator is in place. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516397

Either way I do thank you again for the help!